# How to get union types of a class property when using ReflectionProperty?

Tags: php, php-8

I am trying to get the union types of a property on a class using `ReflectionProperty`. But having no luck.

```
class Document 
{
   // Standard type
   public string $companyTitleStandard;

   // Union types
   public DocumentFieldCompanyTitle|string $companyTitleUnion;
}
```

Standard type works fine. Union types however, I cannot for love nor money figure out how to implement.

```
$rp = new ReflectionProperty(Document::class, 'companyTitleStandard');
echo $rp->getType()->getName(); // string

$rp = new ReflectionProperty(Document::class, 'companyTitleUnion');
echo $rp->getTypes(); // Exception: undefined method ReflectionProperty::getTypes()    
echo $rp->getType()->getTypes(); // Exception: undefined method ReflectionNamedType::getTypes()
```

I'm ultimately looking for something like this to play with:

```
['DocumentFieldCompanyTitle', 'string']
```

Any ideas anyone? Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, I reverted the question to include your attempt (which you for some reason removed) and to match what I actually answered below.

Comment: Thank you for your time M Eriksson. This caught me out I'm sure it will help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On union types, the first

```
$rp->getType()
```

will return a [ReflectionUnionType](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionuniontype.php).
To get the names of the individual types in the union, you then need to iterate through

```
$rp->getType()->getTypes()
```

So to just output the types:

```
foreach ($rp->getType()->getTypes() as $type) {
    echo $type->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

If you rather get the types for union in a normal array, you can do this:

```
$unionTypes = array_map(function($type) { 
    return $type->getName();
}, $rp->getType()->getTypes());
```

Or for short in a one-liner:

```
$unionTypes = array_map(fn($type) => $type->getName(), $rp->getType()->getTypes());
```

Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/SlbXX#v8.0.19